# using left outer join on a single table comparing values from third table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a single Table for Status having the following rows:

```
pk   Status

1    Employed

2    Unemployed

3    Retired
```

And one more table named User wherein the details are stored as

```
 pk_User  F_Status   M_Status

    1         1         2

    2         2         3

    3         3         1
```

wherein the values of `F_status` and `M_Status` are referred to the main Table Status.
Now the problem is that i need to display the values and using the left outer join however i cannot use a same table for the same..

My Query is:

```
select Status from User  
left outer join Status on
Status.pk=User.M_Status
where  pk_User=1;
```

Here i can only display one single row and not both. Please help

Answer Should be:

```
pk_User | F_Status  | M_Status
--------+-----------+------------
      1 | Employeed | Unemployeed
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: pk_User | F_Status  |  M_Status

1       | Employeed |  Unemployeed

Comment: I think what @Shafeeq asked was to see the exact ouput of the query that you are expecting to get, not just the column names which provide close to none information

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : the below is the answer expected as the id is given it should track it to the status table and give the appropriate status

Comment: Aha, sorry. I got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  u.pk_User,
  fs.status AS F_Status,
  ms.status AS M_Status
FROM user u
INNER JOIN status fs ON u.f_status = fs.pk
INNER JOIN status ms ON u.m_status = ms.pk
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d84d/6)

This will give you:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ PK_USER  ║  F_STATUS   ║  M_STATUS  ║
╠══════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║       3  ║ Retired     ║ Employed   ║
║       1  ║ Employed    ║ Unemployed ║ <-------
║       2  ║ Unemployed  ║ Retired    ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to filter on `PK_User` or any other column.

Comment: @user3114651 - Are you sure that the tables' structures and the columns' names as you posted in the question `user`(`pk_User`, `F_Status`, `M_Status`), `status`(`pk`, `Status`)? if not please post the tables, structures in the question.

Comment: @user3114651 - What is error you got? show me please the error.

Comment: :It worked..was making a mistake with the primary key of the two tables

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are trying to do a multiple join on both `m_status` and `f_status` to the same table.

```
SELECT fs.f_status, ms.m_status FROM user u
INNER JOIN status fs ON u.f_status = fs.status
INNER JOIN status ms ON u.m_status = ms.status
WHERE u.pk_user = 1;
```